# Error in fail: Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find Java binary

Tags: java, android, bazel, mediapipe, bazel-rules

I m trying to run handtracking example in the mediapipe package
and when I run the building command using bazel I get the error below

```
   ERROR: C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel:3:10: in fail_rule rule @local_jdk//:jdk:
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/fail_rule.bzl", line 19, column 13, in _fail_rule_impl
                fail("%s %s" % (ctx.attr.header, ctx.attr.message))
Error in fail: Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find Java binary bin/java.exe in C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/install/b88b7745f304d609d2d5d80b0c77ba96/embedded_tools/tools/jdk/nosystemjdk; e
ither correct your JAVA_HOME, PATH or specify embedded Java (e.g. --javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk11)
INFO: Repository remotejdk11_win instantiated at:
  /DEFAULT.WORKSPACE.SUFFIX:193:6: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl:201:18: in maybe
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository remote_java_tools_windows instantiated at:
  /DEFAULT.WORKSPACE.SUFFIX:248:6: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl:201:18: in maybe
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository XNNPACK instantiated at:
  C:/users/admin/mediapipe_repo/mediapipe/WORKSPACE:410:14: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace2.bzl:1097:21: in workspace
  C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace2.bzl:128:20: in _tf_repositories
  C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:112:21: in tf_http_archive
Repository rule _tf_http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/hfz472l7/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:65:35: in <toplevel>
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@local_jdk//:jdk' fail
ed
INFO: Elapsed time: 7.657s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (6 packages loaded, 8162 targets configured)
```

Comment: Have you installed Java?

Comment: yes, it was installed this problem has been fixed after running bazel clean .thanks for your comment @binjamin