# Error in fail: Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find Java binary bin/java

Tags: java, bazel

I am using the following configuration on an up-to-date Debian Testing:

```
$ bazel version
Bazelisk version: v1.10.1
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
Build label: 4.0.0
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Jan 21 07:33:24 2021 (1611214404)
Build timestamp: 1611214404
Build timestamp as int: 1611214404
```

I have openjdk 11 (currently 11.0.11) installed and `update-alternatives` points to it via `/usr/bin/java`. Environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is **unset**.

In this configuration the following command fails:

```
$ bazel coverage --config=linux_x86 -c dbg --instrumentation_filter="//implementation:atos_utest" //implementation/src/utest:all 2>&1 | tee /tmp/buildlog.txt
2021/07/30 16:40:49 Downloading https://releases.bazel.build/4.0.0/release/bazel-4.0.0-linux-x86_64...
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
    currently loading: implementation/src/utest
Analyzing: 27 targets (1 packages loaded)
Analyzing: 27 targets (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: 27 targets (18 packages loaded, 73 targets configured)
Analyzing: 27 targets (27 packages loaded, 144 targets configured)
ERROR: /home/atoml/.cache/bazel/_bazel_atoml/ababbc8a7f78bac9d28b91a651da5105/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel:3:10: in fail_rule rule @local_jdk//:jdk: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/atoml/.cache/bazel/_bazel_atoml/ababbc8a7f78bac9d28b91a651da5105/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/fail_rule.bzl", line 19, column 13, in _fail_rule_impl
        fail("%s %s" % (ctx.attr.header, ctx.attr.message))
Error in fail: Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find Java binary bin/java in /home/atoml/.cache/bazel/_bazel_atoml/install/1a4a2fac02d50c77031d44c0d91b8920/embedded_tools/tools/jdk/nosystemjdk; either correct your JAVA_HOME, PATH or specify embedded Java (e.g. --javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk11)
ERROR: Analysis of target '//implementation/src/utest:uut_compdb' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@local_jdk//:jdk' failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 7.681s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (29 packages loaded, 367 targets configured)
ERROR: Couldn't start the build. Unable to run tests
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (29 packages loaded, 367 targets configured)
```

Other build commands succeed. This is a VM setup, on other VM instances with the same configuration as described above, this command succeeds.

I'd be grateful for hints.  Simple things like `bazel clean` as in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68481735/error-in-fail-auto-configuration-error-cannot-find-java-binary) do not help, I have even removed the build cache completely, but to no avail. BTW. my build has nothing to do with android.

Comment: Could you add the output of `java --version` to your question? For me, I just didn't have a jdk installed, so I needed to do `sudo apt install default-jdk`

Comment: The VM is now running "bullseye" and the issue is no longer there!?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but I resolved it with the correct installation of the jdk. Check that your version of bazel does not mark this Warning:

```
bazel version 
Bazelisk version: v1.11.0
**WARNING: Ignoring JAVA_HOME, because it must point to a JDK, not a JRE.**
Build label: 4.2.1
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Mon Aug 30 15:17:47 2021 (1630336667)
Build timestamp: 1630336667
Build timestamp as int: 1630336667
```

If this warning appears, it means that we have a problem with the jdk, validate that you have the javac command installed with the following command:

```
javac -version
```

If it is not installed, look for the installation for your platform, in my case it is with the following command:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Finally verify the installation directory with the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Make sure you have the JAVA_HOME configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have retested for the first time since long, and the issue seems to be gone.  The VM is running `bullseye`.

Bazel version:

```
$ bazel version
Bazelisk version: v1.10.1
Build label: 4.2.1
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Mon Aug 30 15:17:47 2021 (1630336667)
Build timestamp: 1630336667
Build timestamp as int: 1630336667
```

Java version:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Maybe a heisenbug ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing error message - it says it can't find `bin/java` but I did have `java` available on my system.

The issue is that I had the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) which lets you run Java programs with the `java` command, but I did not have the JDK (Java Development Environment) which lets you *compile* Java code with the `javac` command. That's what Bazel actually wants.

I'm on RHEL 8 so I installed it like this:

```
sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```